# Are there anyway to apply MDL effect after page is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, material-design-lite

I have a question for Material Design Lite.
In general, the page is loaded and then checkbox or text special effects will be applied, so that the checkbox and text box is working. But I am now using reactJS to dynamically load the dialog. This means, the contents of the dialog will be generated after the main page is loaded.
But I found in this way, all the checkbox / text effect is no longer applied.
May I ask if there are any special API that I can call to manually apply MDL effect after page is loaded? Just like those:

```
textDom.text() or checkDom.check()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to call

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

after you have dynamically loaded your changes.

Comment: sorry Michael to miss your reply. But where is componentHandler? How to import it? I got "Cannot find name 'componentHandler'." error

Comment: The `componentHandler`is in the material-JS. So if you have included it in your project, you have it available in your JS. `<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am now using angular2, and I want to use componentHandler, but when it get compiled, I always got error "Cannot find name 'componentHandler'." Any idea how to import this into angular2 project? This is what I am testing:  ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log( window.componentHandler );
    }

Comment: My fault, I have to put "declare var componentHandler: any;" in the beginning. Now everything is good